# My program is not printing the string without 'g' and/or 'n'. Why is it so?

Tags: java, operators

Here is my code:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String y)
    {
        int l =y.length();
        for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++)
        {
            if(y.charAt(i)!='g'||y.charAt(i)!='n')
        System.out.print(y.charAt(i));
        else
        continue;
    }}
}
```

I think && would work.
Or operator checks if only one statement is true.
Therefore, result will always be true and the input string would be same to output string.

Comment: `c != 'g' || c != 'n'` is always `true` should be `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used OR (||) insted of AND (&&)

This code will always return true:

```
(y.charAt(i)!='g' || y.charAt(i)!='n')
```

Try this instead:

```
    public class test 
    { 
        public static void main(String y) 
        { 
            int l =y.length(); 
            for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++) 
            { 
                if(y.charAt(i)!='g' && y.charAt(i)!='n') 
                    System.out.print(y.charAt(i)); 
                else continue; 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String y)
    {
        int l =y.length();
        for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++)
        {
            if( y.charAt(i) == 'g'|| y.charAt(i) == 'n'){
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.print(y.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

}
```